# Seleccionar campos especificos

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mvc, asp.net-core

necesito seleccionar solo unos determinados campos, pero no logro interpretar como se hace.

```
ReportAuditUser reportUser = new ReportAuditUser();
reportUser.Id = Convert.ToInt32 (row[1]);
string userInfo = row[2].ToString();
var info = GetSplittedString(userInfo);
```

Comment: Que tipo de variable es`row` ?

Comment: Es un DataRow..

Comment: Pero entonces no entiendo la duda, si es una sola row entonces al usar row[1] estas tomando el valor de la segunda columna, recuerda que las las columnas comienzan con la cero

Comment: Entonces me exprese mal, lo que necesito es obtener todos los datos que trae esa row  y desglosar 1x1 esos datos para que se puedan mostrar en la view.

Comment: pero n se supone que cada columna de la row debe mapear con una propiedad de la entidad? si es asi entonces sigue con el mismo que ya aplicas, usando row[x] para asignar a las propiedades

Comment: Como te comenta @LeandroTuttini o lo haces "manualmente al mapeo", o lo tratas de convertir a dynamic, o algo mas generico (pero bueno, si es solo para este caso del ejemplo te convendria manual)

Answer (score 0):

Como te comentan para mapear un DataRow a un objeto

1. O lo haces manualmente, propiedad por propiedad a cada columna (incluso si es una lista de objecto claro ya que es DataRow dentro de un Datatable generalmente)
2. O intentas mapear un DataRow a Dynamic (hay ejemplos de pasar a JSON y deserializarlo en dynamic)
3. O algo mas "genérico", que paso el enlace mas abajo

Para este ultimo punto se podría probar este código interesante

- [Como convertir DataRow a Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19673502/how-to-convert-datarow-to-an-object)

Arme un ejemplo en un repo si lo quieres ver con test y demo de consola

- GitHub > datatable-to-object-mapper > https://github.com/fernandezja/datatable-to-object-mapper

Por ejemplo [manualmente (propiedad por propiedad)](https://github.com/fernandezja/datatable-to-object-mapper/blob/c84a1e8bcd104a8b9c23a7dbdc8ff8e3a0976020/src/ConsoleApp1/Program.cs#L23), es decir aqui es donde seleccionas que campos mapear... y convertir al tipo de dato correcto (si solo queres hacerlo para una sola ves convendria hacerlo asi)

```
  private static void DemoManualDataRowToObjectJedi()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Demo Manual: DataRow to Jedi object");

        var jedisDataTable = GenerateJedisDataTable();

        DataRow jediDataRow = jedisDataTable.Rows[0];

        var jedi = new Jedi() { 
            Id = Convert.ToInt32(jediDataRow["Id"]),
            Name = Convert.ToString(jediDataRow["Name"]),
        };

        Console.WriteLine($"Jedi: Id={jedi.Id} Name={jedi.Name}");

    }
```

ALgo mas generico, es con el codigo que pase de ejemplo es decir mapearlo automaticamente a un objeto donde cada columna del datarow tenga su correspondiente nombre de propiedad en el objeto, ejemplo con el metodo extensor ToObject

```
var jedi = jediDataRow.ToObject<Jedi>();
```

Siguiendo con el ejemplo del repo

```
 private static void DemoSimpleAutomaticDataRowToObjectJedi()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Demo Simple Automatic: DataRow to Jedi object");

        var jedisDataTable = GenerateJedisDataTable();

        DataRow jediDataRow = jedisDataTable.Rows[0];

        var jedi = jediDataRow.ToObject<Jedi>();

        Console.WriteLine($"Jedi: Id={jedi.Id} Name={jedi.Name}");

    }
```

Se podría agregar la funcionalidad de **seleccionar campos específicos**, por ejemplo decorar con algún atributo nuestra propiedad del modelo (el objeto) para que esos campos no se mapeen, o enviar un array de propiedades/columnas que no se quieren mapear. Pero esto te dejo como inquietud si necesitas algo muy genérico, y quieras extender el método extensor genérico.

Aquí dejo el [método extensor ToObject para mapear genéricamente un DataRow a un Objeto tipado](https://github.com/fernandezja/datatable-to-object-mapper/blob/c84a1e8bcd104a8b9c23a7dbdc8ff8e3a0976020/src/DataRowMapper/DataRowExtensions.cs#L15)

```
public static class DataRowExtensions
{
    public static T ToObject<T>(this DataRow dataRow) where T : new()
    {
        T item = new T();

        foreach (DataColumn column in dataRow.Table.Columns)
        {
            PropertyInfo property = GetProperty(typeof(T), column.ColumnName);

            if (property != null && dataRow[column] != DBNull.Value && dataRow[column].ToString() != "NULL")
            {
                property.SetValue(item, ChangeType(dataRow[column], property.PropertyType), null);
            }
        }

        return item;
    }

    private static PropertyInfo GetProperty(Type type, string attributeName)
    {
        PropertyInfo property = type.GetProperty(attributeName);

        if (property != null)
        {
            return property;
        }

        return type.GetProperties()
             .Where(p => p.IsDefined(typeof(DisplayAttribute), false) 
                        && p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), false).Cast<DisplayAttribute>().Single().Name == attributeName)
             .FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public static object ChangeType(object value, Type type)
    {
        if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition().Equals(typeof(Nullable<>)))
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            return Convert.ChangeType(value, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type));
        }

        return Convert.ChangeType(value, type);
    }
}
```

Espero que sirva de ayuda o guia